# Save php json object into jquery variables

Tags: php, jquery, json

I would take a php json object and save it in a jquery variable.

```
<?php
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $arr[] = array('id'=>$i, 'text'=>$i);
}
$arr = json_encode($arr);
?>
<input id="phpObj" type="hidden" value="" data-items='<?php echo $arr; ?>'>
```

browser html source display

```
<input id="phpObj" type="hidden" data-items="[{"id":0,"text":0},{"id":1,"text":1},{"id":2,"text":2},{"id":3,"text":3},{"id":4,"text":4}]">
```

For get the php object I did it this way

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON($('#phpObj').data('items'));
console.log(data);
```

but I've this error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

I tried to use `jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify($('#phpObj').data('items')));`
but with no success. `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`

How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: directly do this :- `var data = $.parseJSON('<?php echo $arr;?>');`

Comment: Or `<input id="phpObj" type="hidden" value='<?php echo $arr; ?>'>` and  `var data = $.parseJSON($('#phpObj').val());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working example for you:-

```
<?php
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $arr[] = array('id'=>$i, 'text'=>$i);
}
$arr = json_encode($arr);
?>
<input id="phpObj" type="hidden" data-items='<?php echo $arr; ?>'>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = $.parseJSON($('#phpObj').attr("data-items"));
console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

Output:- On my local screen:- http://prntscr.com/akrz2w

Answer (score 2):

The JSON string contains the same type of quotes that you use to wrap the data value. Try to use single quotes instead.